# Корректный запрос к БД many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql

Имеем 3 таблицы:

1. teacher (teacherid, tname, sex, phone)
2. student (studentid, sname, mail, level, brithday)
3. t_s (id, teacherid, studentid)

Необходимо создать запрос к *БД*, который выведет:
Имя учителя, пол, номер телефона, его учеников.

Пробовал делать вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT *,
 GROUP_CONCAT(student.sname ORDER BY student.sname ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS sname
FROM teacher
INNER JOIN t_s ON teacher.teacherid = t_s.teacherid
INNER JOIN student ON t_s.studentid = student.studentid
GROUP BY teacher.teacherid ASC
```

Данный запрос меня полностью удовлетворяет за исключением одного маленького «но»: он выводит только учителей с учениками, и если у учителя нет учеников, то ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `INNER JOIN` на `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста еще, данный вывод выводит дату рождения ученика, а если мне необходимо фильтровать вывод только тех учителей, у которых ученики родились в 04 месяце. Не пойму куда добавить строку WHERE brithday LIKE '____-08-__'

Comment: 1) Так все-таки в 04 или в 08 месяце? 2) Надеюсь, Вы все же храните дату не строкой, а в поле типа `DATE`? Тогда надо использовать функцию `MONTH()`: `WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 8`. 3) Кляуза `WHERE` используется перед `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Опечатка у меня. Да, храню дату в поле DATE. Использовал функцию MONTH(), все прекрасно работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста еще, у меня есть цикл while, по которому я прогоняю данный запрос, строка $sname = $row['sname']; выводит имена учеников через запятую, а как подсчитать количество значений, которые вывела эта строка?

Comment: Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, плодить вопросы-ответы в комментариях — это как-то неправильно. К тому же я не настолько хорошо знаком с PHP и MySQL, чтобы сходу ответить, а кроме меня тут уже мало кто увидит этот вопрос. :)

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь :) Решил эту проблему разбивкой строки по запятой, с проверкой пуста ли строка.